# Label, font programmatically

Tags: swift, fonts, textview, label

I need help in this view.
I have to solve these things:
- instead of the 2 "duck" labels, I need to have different `label.text` with different fonts. I used this method here, in which I assign all the fonts to my *datasource* and assign the label to it by changing the font. the final result must be, for example, "duck" "ciccio" and "another"..

- At the moment the view in which to insert the text is not connected to the colors or the fonts, I have to be able to insert the text and then if I click on a color it automatically changes the color to the written text and so the same thing for the fonts ..

What do I have to do?

I am attaching part of the code, only the one in which I put the "duck" label and the controller of the whole view.

[that I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agncT.jpg)

```
class CollectionFont: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    weak var delegate: FontDelegate?
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    let cellSpacing:CGFloat = 1
    let indexPath: IndexPath
    var datasource: [UIFont] = []
    var imageArray: Array<UIImageView> = []
    var onceOnly = false

    init(datasource: [UIFont], index: IndexPath = [0,0]) {
        self.indexPath = index
        self.datasource = Theme.CustomFontsFamily.customFonts
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
        collectionView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView!)
        collectionView!.activate(constraint(edgesTo: self.view))
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = Theme.Colors.sky
        let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionView!.setCollectionViewLayout(collectionViewFlowLayout, animated: true)
        collectionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        collectionView!.register(FontCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: FontCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView!.bounces = false
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    class FontRound {
        let font: UILabel

        init(font: UILabel) {
            self.font = font
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.datasource.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FontCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FontCell
        cell.array.font = self.datasource[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    //UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout - constraint della collecion view da innestare
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/4
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/4
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        debugPrint("sucaaaa")
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        var visibleRect = CGRect()
        visibleRect.origin = collectionView!.contentOffset
        visibleRect.size = collectionView!.bounds.size
        let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
        guard let indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) else { return }
        print(indexPath[1])
        self.delegate?.sincronizeScroll(indexPath: indexPath)
    }

    internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if !onceOnly {
            //set the row and section you need.
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: self.indexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.right, animated: false)
            onceOnly = true
        }
    }
}

final class CollectionFontView: UICollectionView {

    init(_ collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        register(FontCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: FontCell.reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


class FontCell: UICollectionViewCell {
static let reuseIdentifier = "FontCell_RID"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

var cellID: String?

var array = UILabel().then{
    $0.text = "duck"
    $0.font = UIFont(name:"Jellee-Roman",size:15)
    $0.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    $0.layer.cornerRadius = (((UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/8)*0.8)/2)
}

func setupViews(){
    self.addSubview(self.array)
    self.array.activate([
        array.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
        array.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.array.widthAnchor),
        array.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
        array.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
        ])
}

func setContents(container: UILabel) {
    for sv in self.contentView.subviews {
        sv.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    self.contentView.addSubview(container)
    container.activate(constraint(edgesTo: self.contentView))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: Please add some more of your code from the view controller you're presenting.

Comment: @Callam ok.. I update thx

Comment: @Callam insert bro.. thx for helping

Comment: Could you please write "duck" or something not vulgar? Inside your code or inside the screenshot?

Comment: @Larme I think I did, what's the problem?

Comment: It's unclear what's currently working and what it isn't. But instead of doing `debugPrint("sucaaaa")`, do `let font = self.datasource[indexPath.row]; theViewInTheMiddle.font = font`?

Comment: @Larme I can't understand bro.. sorry.. can you tell me more?